# I want to target <a> tag in WordPress menu and add an element outside of there

Tags: wordpress, hook-wordpress

I have used the wp_nav_menu_objects fillter hook in wordpress to add an element outside of  tag.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqwNF.png)

```
// menu items
```

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_wp_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2);

function my_wp_nav_menu_objects( $items, $args ) {

```
// loop
foreach( $items as &$item ) {
    // vars
        $language = get_field('chinese_name', $item);
    
    // append icon
    if( $language ) {
        
        $item->title .= ' <span class="menu_link_back ch">'.$language.'</span>';
        
    }
    
}


// return
return $items;
```

}

That's the code. But this shows the element inside of the  tag but I want it to be on the outside.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qOC3.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65712216/3645650

Comment: Thanks. But I have fixed it with something else.